# Select values from a single table considering a first select as a condition

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite table where I store information about the company/branches with the following structure:

```
   id  |  id_branch  |  username  | position |  
-------+-------------+------------+----------
   1   |     111     |     ana    |  manager
   2   |     222     |    steph   |  officer
   3   |     111     |    carl    |  officer
   4   |     111     |    alex    |  officer
```

Given a username, I need to retrieve the ids according to the following rules:

1. if the position of the given username is a manager, bring me all the ids of everybody that works for the same id_branch. Example: given "ana", I should get 1, 3 and 4 as a result, once she is a manager.
2. if the position of the given username is an officer, bring only the id of himself. Example: given "carl", I should get only 3 as a result, once he is an officer.

How would I do this conditional select statement in SQL?

Comment: Could you show us your expect result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is tempting to approach this as a `union all` query.  However, you can detect those conditions with a simple self-join:

```
select t.*
from t cross join
     t tu
where tu.username = ? and
      ( (tu.position = 'manager' and t.branch_id = tu.branch_id) or
        (tu.position = 'officer' and t.id = tu.id)
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use self-join with some condition.

**Schema (SQLite v3.18)**

```
CREATE TABLE T (
   id int,
   id_branch int,
   username varchar(50),
   position varchar(50)
);


 insert into T values (1,111,'ana' ,'manager');
 insert into T values (2,222,'steph'  ,'officer');
 insert into T values (3,111,'carl'  ,'officer');
 insert into T values (4,111,'alex'  ,'officer');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM T t1 
INNER JOIN T t2 On 
    t1.id_branch = t2.id_branch and t1.position = 'manager' 
 or 
    t1.id = t2.id and t1.position = 'officer'
where t1.username = 'ana';

| id  | id_branch | username | position |
| --- | --------- | -------- | -------- |
| 1   | 111       | ana      | manager  |
| 3   | 111       | carl     | officer  |
| 4   | 111       | alex     | officer  |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p3Q6N8n7wA4j3UGA1wxmcv/0)